# Publish sbt artifact to filesystem

Tags: sbt

I have an internal maven repository located at `file:///some/path/here`.  I would like to publish my sbt artifacts to this location.  I gleaned that the following should work.

```
publishMavenStyle := true

publishTo <<= version { (v: String) =>
  val path = "file:///some/path/here/"
  if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
    Some("snapshots" at nexus + "maven-snapshots")
  else
    Some("releases"  at nexus + "maven")
}
```

However, this fails with the following exception.

```
[info]  delivering ivy file to .../target/scala-2.9.2/ivy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: URL repository only support HTTP PUT at the moment
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:202)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
```

How can I publish artifacts using sbt to a repository specified by a file path?

Comment: Here is a related problem with no solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/simple-build-tool/m1ogeyCPinQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this format to publish to a local file path:

```
publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", new File("/some/path/here")))
```