# Publishing an sbt artifact to the filesystem, with resolver specified in ~/.sbt/repositories file

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

This is a question very closely related to [Publish sbt artifact to filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858927/publish-sbt-artifact-to-filesystem). The difference is that I'm specifying the resolver in the ~/.sbt/repositories file, and don't get to write `Resolver.file` as the answer specifies.

I'm on sbt 0.13.5. My file looks something like

```
[repositories]
  local
  myrepo: file://path/to/my/repo/, <someivypattern>
```

and when I attempt to publish to it, I get the usual error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: URL repository only support HTTP PUT at the moment
```

I've attempted different ways to specify the repo path, but it always seems to demand a protocol specification, which then seems to prevent me from publishing to it if I use `file:/`.

How do I publish using the `repositories` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this wasn't possible. I fixed it in [this pull request](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1579), so it is now.